# Django looking for template that doesn't exist

Tags: python, django

I made some major changes to my site and now when I click a specific link, it tries to go to a page that doesn't exist (rightfully so) but I can't find any reference to that non-existent page in my code so I can't direct it properly.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import BakingPost
from django.views import generic


def index(request):
    num_posts = BakingPost.objects.all().count()
    context = {
        'num_posts': num_posts,
    }
    return render(request, 'food_blog/index.html', context=context)


class BakingListView(generic.ListView):
    model = BakingPost
    # paginate_by = 10


class BakingDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = BakingPost
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('bakes/', views.BakingListView.as_view(), name='bakes'),
    path('bake/<int:pk>/', views.BakingDetailView.as_view(), name='bake_detail'),
    # path('post/new/', views.post_new, name='post_new'),
    # path('post/<int:pk>/edit/', views.post_edit, name='post_edit'),
]
```

navbar.html

```
<nav>
  <div id="div_navbar">
    <ul class="ul_navbar">
      <li class="li_navbar">
        <a class="a_navbar" href="{% url 'index' %}">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="li_navbar">
        <a class="a_navbar" href="{% url 'bakes' %}">Baking List</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

bake_list.html

```
{% extends 'food_blog/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>Baking List</h1>
    {% if bake_list %}
    <ul>
        {% for bake in bake_list %}
            <li>
                <a href="{{ bake.get_absolute_url }}">{{ bake.title }}</a> ({{bake.author}})
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {% else %}
        <p>Nothing in the oven</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

When I click on "Baking List" on the navbar on my homepage, it errors out saying "TemplateDoesNotExist at /bakes/
food_blog/bakingpost_list.html". The error is correct, that file doesn't exist anywhere but I'm not sure why it's looking for bakingpost_list.html. I created that file and then renamed it to bake_list.html and I thought I caught all references to it in views.py and urls.py. I still haven't found anything in my code that points to "bakingpost_list.html". Struggling to figure out if this error means something else.

I tried to change the Template directory in settings.py like some other posts suggested but that didn't work and I don't think this is the same issue. Django is able to find everything else that is in the Templates directory.

For fun , I created a new file "bakingpost_list.html" in the same templates directory as all my other html files and it loads that page fine. So I'm assuming somewhere I've forgotten to stop referencing that file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is default template name for [ListView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview)

To be more concise it inherited  from [MultipleObjectTemplateResponseMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectTemplateResponseMixin) class and it is generated by [`get_template_names()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectTemplateResponseMixin.get_template_names)

> Returns a list of candidate template names. Returns the following
> list:
>
> the value of template_name on the view (if provided)
> <app_label>/<model_name><template_name_suffix>.html

Comment: http://ccbv.co.uk/ is very useful for inspecting the attributes and methods that the generic views have http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/3.0/django.views.generic.list/ListView/#get_template_names

Answer (score 1):

You can add your desired template to the view if you don’t want the default template, like:

```
class BakingListView(generic.ListView):
    model = BakingPost
    template_name = ‘bakes/food_blog/bake_list.html’
    # paginate_by = 10
```